# Css positioning, positioning issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to positioning the name of the website to the top left of the page .I have the name of the page in foodies.com and in css i used the position:relative; top:10%; left :10%; but its displaying at near the  middle of the page. Does anyone have any solutions. i am really struggling with positioning

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.intro {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background:url(https://picstatio.com/download/1600x900/864423/food-dishes-beer-bottle.jpg)no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.intro .inner{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}
.name{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 0%;
}
.content {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.content h1  {
 font-family: "Yantramana";
 font-size: 600%;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #E1EFE9;
 line-height: 70%;
}
.btn{
 font-family: "montserrat";
 font-size: 135%;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: orange;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 9px;
 transition: all 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
 color: #CBDFD6;
 border: solid #CBDFD6;
}
.about-us{
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
}
.ab-content {
 font-family: "Poiret One";
 font-weight: lighter;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 150%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.ab-p{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-family: "montserrat";
}
h2{
 text-align: center;
}
h3{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "montserrat";
}
.ab-2p{
 font-family:"montserrat";
 font-size: 22px;
 margin:  10px 10px; 
}
ul {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 0 50px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 35px;
 line-height: 80px;
 display: block;
 border:  3px solid orange;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: orange;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
ul li a .fab{
 position: relative;
 color: orange;
 transition: .5s;
}
ul li a:hover .fab {
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.color {
 color:orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Foodies</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
   <h1 class="name">Foodies<span class="blue">.com</span></h1>
   <div class="content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
     <h1>Find <span class="color">Your</span> Taste!</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="about-us">
  <div class="ab-inner">
   <div class="ab-content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <h2 class="center"><span class="color">Our Mission</span></h2>
     <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".5s">
      <p class="ab-p">Our mission is to provide the best food ingedients.</p>
      <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".5s">
       <h3 class="ab-content"><span class="color">About</span></h3>
       <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".6s">
        <p class="ab-2p">Cooking is all about people. Food is maybe the only universal thing that really has the power to bring everyone together. No matter what culture, everywhere around the world, people get together to eat.Cooking is like snow skiing: If you don't fall at least 10 times, then you're not skiing hard enough.The fast-food industry is in very good company with the lead industry and the tobacco industry in how it tries to mislead the public, and how aggressively it goes after anybody who criticizes its business practices.The problem is when that fun stuff becomes the habit. And I think that's what's happened in our culture. Fast food has become the everyday meal.</p>
        <h3 class="ab-content"><span class="color">Soical Media</span></h3>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
        </ul>   
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to be working fine in the snippet, please create a [mcve] demonstrating your actual problem - emphasis on minimal

Comment: I would use `position:absolute` if you know you always want it in a certain location as `relative` still reserves space in the normal flow of the document for where the element originally was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would revise the `inner` container that contains both the `name` and the `content`

Make the container not align things in the middle

```
.intro .inner {        
    vertical-align: initial; 
}
```

Use margin to push the header and content into correct position

```
.name {
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Hopefully that is closer to your desired layout.

Comment: Thanks . your suggestions worked . can where you learnt stuff like that

Comment: No secrets, just experience. Do a lot of web design and you'll get the hang of it